# "screen" exit by itself after broken ssh?

Tags: ssh, screen

I'm on Mac and `ssh` to a server (Ubuntu 18.04) to run a long Python job. I started the job in a `screen` session and then detached the screen.

After a few minutes, I receive a message `packet_write_wait: Connection to 128.122.136.109 port 22: Broken pipe` from my local terminal.

Then I reconnected to the server using `ssh`, and when I try to resume the screen session I got `There is no screen to be resumed.`.

This is weird as I suppose `screen` should still be running even after the `ssh` is broken? This has also happened at least three times so it's not an incident.

What could go wrong, and how should I debug and repair it? Thanks!

Comment: Any chance the server crashed/was rebooted during that interval?  Did you check the uptime?

Comment: @BowlOfRed yes this is probably the issue. The uptime is suspiciously short. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the `ssh` connection and the `screen` session are handled by running processes and both will be lost with a server reboot.  You should check the server uptime, or look for boot indications in the messages file.

If it has rebooted, you'll need to diagnose that separately.